# Can we turn this specific product of sums into a sum of products?

Tags: combinatorics, products

I am interested in turning this product into a sum (especially in the case N=4 and $A_j$ is a scalar):
$$\prod_{k=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^k A_j$$
Do you see a nice way to do the combinatorics?

Comment: For $N=4$ we have $ a_1^4 + 3 a_1^3 a_2  + 2 a_1^3 a_3  +  a_1^3 a_4 + 3 a_1^2 a_2^2 + 4 a_1^2 a_2 a_3 + 2 a_1^2 a_2 a_4 +  a_1^2 a_3 a_4 + a_1 a_2^3 +
2 a_1 a_2^2 a_3 + a_1 a_2^2 a_4 + a_1 a_2 a_3^2 +  a_1 a_2 a_3 a_4 +  a_2^2 a_3^2.$ The coefficient sequence $ 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 4, 2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1$ does not give hits in OEIS. Guess its a hard problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To add to Axel Kemper's response, we could move the product all the way to the right, but this would necessitate many sums.

$$\prod_{k=1}^N\sum_{j=1}^kA_j=\sum_{k_1=1}^1\sum_{k_2=1}^2...\sum_{k_N=1}^N\prod_{j=1}^NA_{k_j}$$